# Combine 2 tables in laravel

Tags: jquery, database, laravel

I want to combine my Users Table and AcitvationCodes table and display them in a single foreach loop. My ActivationCodes table has a foreign key 'user_id'. Here is my code:

```
$data['codes'] = ActivationCode::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(15);
```

in my foreach loop i added this and it doesn't work. Please help.

```
 @foreach($codes as $p)
           @php $rr = \App\User::where('id',$p->user_id)->first(); @endphp
           <td>{{$rr->name}} </td>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to load activation codes which do not have any user attached `where('user_id', 0)`. Then you're trying to get code's user `User::where('id', $p->user_id)`. Of course, this will not work, because codes you loaded do not have any user. You may load all activation codes with its user:

```
ActivationCode::with('user')->latest('id')->paginate(15);
```

And then display related user without executing a new query for each user:

```
@foreach($codes as $code)
    <td>{{ $code->user->name }}</td>
@endforeach
```

To make it work you need to have this relationship defined:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: Call to undefined relationship [user] on model [App\ActivationCode]. i get this error

Comment: @RonaldTorres you have to have a relationship defined. I've assumed you already have it. I've updated the answer.